# How to display string from function call inside concatenation?

Tags: php, laravel, concatenation

I need to join/concatenate strings from a return of a function call, and from a variable without using the traditional concatenation `.`.

In this scenario, it should be displaying a url string.

Below is my actual code.

**CODE:**

```
$test = "{ config('app.url') }/{ $username }";
die(print_r($test));
```

**Current Result:**

```
{ config('app.url') }/testuser
```

**Expected Result:**

```
http://localhost:8000/testuser
```

Comment: Why are you refusing concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may read more about complex (curly) syntax in a quoted string, however you may achieve what you want with that code:

```
$test = "{${config('app.url')}}/{$username}";
die(print_r($test));
```

But I personally prefer:

```
$appUrl = config('app.url');
$test = "{$appUrl}/{$username}";
die(print_r($test));
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: @mickmackusa, good to know that, but I was the first one to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. But the first snippet of code in your comment is not working too. I used the one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You can only parse variables inside string. The only way is assigning function result to variable:

```
$url = config('app.url');
$test = "{$url}/{$username}";
```

You can read more about [Variable parsing in strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [**following way**](https://3v4l.org/bOBcv)

```
<?php

$_ = function ( $v ) { return $v; };

function config($url)
{
    return $url;
}

$username = 'u_name';
echo "{$_( config('app.url') )}/{$username}";
```